# Which layout to use?

Tags: android

I am trying to make one maybe "little diffrent" layout but with no sucess i need to have layout like this:

[image: Layout Screen]

So it should be like:

At the right side 2 text views one for title and one for number and should be few columns. And at the right side only image.

So some kind of a table layout but i wasnt able to manage it with tablelayout. What you will suggest?

Comment: This isn't really the place to ask design questions, you'll probably get yelled at by some of the more uptight users. But that layout looks OK

Comment: You can use relative layout, where you have 2 components (relative to each other) - for example - table and linear, etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about dividing the screen in half with one `TableLayout` and putting a `ListView` with `INFO` items in the left cell (or another `TableLayout` with vertical cells), image in the right one?